# How to run a simple express server inside docker cli?

Tags: rest, express, docker, curl, ip-address

My application is running in multiple docker containers, and I need to trigger commands in them by opening up `docker exec -it cli bash`. The api for my library/application isn't working fully and I'm trying to bootstrap the endeavor using a shell based interaction using shelljs.

I'm following this tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p-x6WdwaJco) to create a simple express server in my docker cli. But my vm'a ip address@app's port isn't able to return my output when I call the api from outside.

I'm calling from my local using: `curl -s -X POST http://104.196.172.177:3000/api/addMember -H "content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -d 'user=Man&address=Moon'` and I'm working on a cloud vm.

server script:

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = 3000
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }))
app.use(bodyParser.json())
//app.get('/', (req, res) => res.send('Hello World!'))
app.use('/api',require('./routes/api'))
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}!`))
```

/routes/api.js:

```
var express= require('express')
var router= express.Router();
router.get('/addMember',function (res, req) {
res.send('adding member')
})
module.exports= router;
```

My guess is that, the ip address is that of the cloud machine and not the docker's. Is this so? -what do I have to do to retrieve the ip?

If something else is wrong- how do I call this api? it has to be running inside the docker cli.

Comment: Can you access logs of this docker container? Console output might be useful here

Comment: can you show your dockerfile? you need to link a port (3000) from your vm to your docker container. and your VM should have port 3000 open in its firewall.